# Question about interface in Solidity

Tags: solidity

[image]

Hey guys, this is a piece of code from Solidity documentation.

These two interfaces *Config* and *NameReg* have never been implemented, how could contract *named* called it? Do I miss something here?

Thx!

Comment: Welcome!  In the future, code snippets are better posted as text instead of an image.  Use the `{}` button in the editor to help with formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 lines of `named` constructor use addresses.  `named` **assumes that the contracts that have already been deployed at those addresses have implemented the interfaces.**

`config` is the contract at `0xd5f9...`.

`config.lookup` returns an `address` so `NameReg` methods like `register` can be invoked.

If the contract at `0xd5f9...` does not have a `lookup` method, its fallback function would be invoked.  Similar case if the `register` method doesn't exist on the address returned by `config.lookup(1)`.